# Given that $f(z)$ is analytic show that $f(\sqrt{z})$ is also analytic

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-zeta, even-and-odd-functions

I am reading Titshmarch book on Riemann zeta function and this is what he says at some point:
[image]

where $$\Xi(z)=\xi\left(\frac{1}{2}+iz\right)$$

Now, he says that because $\Xi(z)$ is analytic and even then $\Xi(\sqrt{z})$ is also analytic. Can someone explain to me why that is? Am I missing something obvious?

And secondly the other statements that I don't quite understand is why can we say that $\Xi(\sqrt{z})$ has infinity of zeros based on the fact that it has order of $\frac{1}{2}$. Thank you for any help on either of tghe statements.

Comment: An entire function with finitely many zeroes will always have integer (or infinite) order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because $\Xi$ is an even function. This means that
$$\Xi(z)=a_0+a_2z^2+a_4z^4+\cdots$$
on the whole complex plane. Therefore
$$\Xi(\sqrt z)=a_0+a_2z+a_4z^2+\cdots$$
is also an entire function.

Comment: Thanks for that, very good and clear answer. Do you mind helping me out with the other statement?

Answer (score 0):

If $f$ is analytic and even on a ball around $0$, then the power series expansion contains only even terms, and hence there is some analytic function $g$ such that $f(z) = g(z^2)$.